# Why am I getting the error **not all arguments converted during string formatting** in my python code?

Tags: python

I searched about it and the other person who posted a similar issue had a typo error but I can't find that in mine.*strong text*

here's the code -

```
num = raw_input("Enter any number: ")
def is_even(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
print is_even(num)
```

Comment: `num` is not a number, it is a string. `string % ...` triggers string formatting, but there are no placeholders in `num`.

Comment: Why don't you link the question here too?

Comment: Try converting it to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `raw_input` to `int`

**Ex:**

```
num = int(raw_input("Enter any number: ")) 
def is_even(x): 
    if x % 2 == 0: 
        return True 
    else: 
        return False 
print is_even(num)
```